# Hibernate cascade remove ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, foreign-key-relationship, cascade

It seems the situation is simply (but it does not work).
Db part (`EVENT_ID` is foreign key. `FK_RR_E_CI` constraint references on `EVENT` table)

```
 |-------|            |----------------|
 | EVENT | 1 ------ ∞ | RECURRENT_RULE |
 |-------|            |----------------|
 | ID    |            | ID             |
 |-------|            | EVENT_ID       |
                      |----------------|
```

Java part:

```
@Entity
public class Event {
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "event")
  private Set<RecurrentRule> recurrentRules = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
public class RecurrentRule {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(columnDefinition = "event_id")
  private Event event;
}
```

If I try to delete event object It will return:

```
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [MY_SCHEMA.FK_RR_E_CI]; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
...
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02292: integrity constraint (MY_SCHEMA.FK_RR_E_CI) violated - child record found
```

`SAVE` and `UPDATE` operations work correctly.

---

What should I change in my mapping to be able use cascade removal?
I know that I should use `@OnDelete(action=OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)` but I can't understand how to use it...

Comment: Please see [mcve]. Show actual DDL, table contents, desired output & query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` attribute in the `@OneToMany` annotation, use Hibernate's `@Cascade()` annotation like this:

```
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "event")
@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
private Set<RecurrentRule> recurrentRules = new HashSet<>();
```

Because `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` is a JPA option, so when Hibernate session tries to delete the object, it will search for a Hibernate Cascade, it won't find it, that's why you should use `@Cascade`.

For further reading take a look at [**Cascade – JPA & Hibernate annotation common mistake**](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/cascade-jpa-hibernate-annotation-common-mistake/), it gives a better explanation.

Comment: Any way same exception because of `Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02292: integrity constraint (MY_SCHEMA.FK_RR_E_CI) violated - child record found` - hibernate should delete at first collection `RecurrentRule ` and than `Event`

Answer (score 2):

It seems has an issue with deep of relations. In hierarchy above `event` I have `calendar` before calendar I have `profile`. To resolve this relations I've used `@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)` but it was not enough for my case. For described case `Event` <=> `RecurrentRule` relation I've implemented listener for Event and I've used one `@EntityListeners({EntityEventJpaCallbacksListener.class})` see `import [javax.persistence.EntityListeners][1];`

```
@Component
public class EntityEventJpaCallbacksListener {
    @PreRemove
    void preRemove(Event event) {
        ContextAware.getBean(RecurrentRuleRepository.class).deleteByEvent(event);
    }
}
```